# Running Flask App on OpenShift 3.5

Tags: python-2.7, flask, openshift

I'm trying to run a very easy flask app with my OpenShift demo account. I created a file app.py with its content as:

```
from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

I pushed it to my git and a build has been triggered. The log in openshift seems Ok but when I hit my URL (as read in the home dashboard) http://my-app.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com I just get the errore saying "Application is not available" .

Should I configure something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application must use port 8080.

By default the Flask development server listens on port 5000.

So use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```